# How to understand valgrind's messages "Invalid write" and "Address is inside a block"?

Tags: memory-management, valgrind

I get the following output from valgrind on my program:

```
==5328== Invalid write of size 2
...
==5328==    by 0x121289: main (flowsim_small.cpp:47)
==5328==  Address 0x1c05b630 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 16 alloc'd
==5328==    at 0x483752F: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
...
```

Ellipsed parts are backtraces, both messages are part of the same messages block.

I am trying to understand what this combination means: "invalid write of size 2" and "address is 0 bytes inside the block of 16".

I have seen many questions and answers on SO and I understand these cases. For exemple, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662008/valgrind-giving-error-but-everything-seems-fine) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24217519/valgrind-invalid-write) one tries to write X bytes at address A in a block of N where A+X > N.

I my case, I don't understand how 2 bytes cannot fit into a memory zone of 16 bytes, starting from byte 0.

Could you explain please?

P.S. I post no code because it is too difficult to narrow down (I use OpenMPI, c++ interfaced with python and a bunch of in-house code) and especially because my question is quite general.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen at least when advanced valgrind features are used, such
as client requests to describe some memory pool management done by
the application or client requests to change the accessibility of the memory.

Without the code, it is however difficult to determine exactly what goes wrong
either in the code or in valgrind.

You might detect if something 'special' is done with the address reported in the
error message by using  valgrind -v -v -v -d -d -d ....
to trace in depth what valgrind is doing.
This will a.o. trace the client requests executed.  If you see a client request
that uses an address that is around the one you see, that might explain.